# Simple SQL query for one table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this one table:

```
ColumnA, ColumnB
C,F
F,C
A,C
C,A
C,F
C,F
C,A
C,F
F,C
X,Y
```

and I need the query to get this output:

```
ColumnA, CoulmnB, Count
C,F,5
A,C,3
X,Y,1
```

Comment: How do you get the count output ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `least()` and `greatest()` to always get column pair values in alphabetic order:

```
select least(ColumnA, ColumnB), greatest(ColumnA, ColumnB), count(*) cnt
from tablename
group by least(ColumnA, ColumnB), greatest(ColumnA, ColumnB)
order by cnt desc
```